# How to manage the life cycle of Connection using epoll(void* event.data.ptr)

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, epoll

I'm using C++ implementation `epoll`.
I want to learn nginx to use `(void*) event.data.ptr` to associate with `Connection`.
`Connection` is a smart pointer. But between `void*` I need to convert the smart pointer to a raw pointer.

There is no increase in the number of references during the conversion and acquisition process, which obviously the program will crash.
So I don't use smart pointer.

I use `new` and `delete`. But it is so terrible.
How to manage the life cycle of `Connection`?

```
int nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, event_list, 100, -1);
for (int n = 0; n < nfds; ++n) {
  auto event = event_list[n];
  auto revents = event.events;

  if (revents & EPOLLIN) {
    if (event.data.fd  == listen_fd_) {
      int fd = handleAccept(listen_fd_);
      auto conn_ptr = std::make_shared<Connection>(fd, connections_manager_);
      //connecions_manager_ is std::set<std::shared_ptr<Connection>>
      //it use start, stop and stop_all manage Connection.
      connections_manager_.start(conn_ptr);
      struct epoll_event ev;
      ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
      ev.data.ptr = static_cast<void*>(conn_ptr.get());
      if (epoll_ctl(event_.getEpollFd(), EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev) == -1) {
        std::cout << "epoll_ctl failed. fd is " << fd << '\n';
        perror("epoll_ctl: fd_");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      continue;
    }
    auto conn = static_cast<Connection *>(event.data.ptr);
    conn->start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general idea that you might want to implement:

- Keep a list of all the `Connection` objects that you create. A simple C-style array would do but you can check the possibility of using an `std::vector`, `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` for the bookkeeping of `Connection` objects.
- Whenever you create a new `Connection`, you would add it to your list before adding it to your `epoll` pool. I'd suggest a separate method `add()` for this.
- Similarly, on closing a `Connection` (from host or client), you need to remove that from `epoll` pool. But, it'll be in your list of connections. You might need a flag e.g. `isClosed` and set it `true` for a closed connection. DON'T delete your `Connection` objects in your `epoll` main event loop. Also, you need something to figure out if there's some data left to send before closing a connection from your side. The client might be waiting up on receiving data from the server.
- For garbage collection of these closed connection, you may use a separate thread with a fixed time interval to go through your list and remove the closed connections.

In general, you might need some wrapper methods for `wait`, `listen`, `add`, `remove`, etc. to decompose your operations. It'd be easier to manage. Additionally, you may have separate thread pools dedicated for read / write operations. Accepting connections in the main event loop is just fine.

Hope that helps!
Let me know if you want to discuss further.

Comment: I had updated my code. I use connection_manager(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Connection>) to manager connection. And add start, stop, stop_all to manager the life cycle of Connection. Thanks.